# Difference between SuspendLayout and BeginUpdate

Tags: .net, winforms, performance, drawing, controls

I do not find a good explanation on what actually the underlying difference is between the two  methods `Control.SuspendLayout` and `BeginUpdate` (typically seen on list controls like `ListView`, `ComboBox`, `ListBox` etc), other than that they both improve performance.

From what I understand:

1. they both suspend drawing until all the items to display are loaded, and repaint after that.
2. typically `SuspendLayout` is called when controls are added to container controls like `Panel`, `GroupBox` etc, while `BeginUpdate` is used for adding non-control items like objects to list controls like `ListBox`.

But why are there two calls when they do the same? Or what do they do differently?

Similarly there is `ResumeLayout` and `EndUpdate` equivalents.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They have nothing in common.  SuspendLayout turns off automatic layout, the kind that's used by controls like TableLayoutPanel and FlowLayoutPanel as well as the layout updates you get from the Dock, Anchor and AutoSize properties.  It has no effect at all on ListView, ComboBox or ListBox, those controls don't perform layout.  You typically only use it when you add controls in bulk to a container.  Sometimes you use it when automatic layout makes resizing the window too obnoxious.  It does reduce the number of repaints, solely by the fact that it suspends control size updates.

BeginUpdate stops a control from repainting itself.  You *do* use it on controls like ListView or ListBox when you add items to them in bulk and can't use their Items.AddRange() method for some reason.

Comment: Hmmm so that begs the question, why is there `SuspendLayout` on non container controls like listboxes and buttons which perform no layout operation. I guess it is a virtual method which is not overridden or implemented in child classes like ListBox and does nothing.

Answer (score 5):

As you pointed yourself, The `BeginUpdate` is part of list controls and used when you adding items.

The `SuspendLayout` is similar but it comes out of `Control` class. It is useful a lot when you do custom draws.

So really, the difference is drawing control vs drawing items in the control. If you set draw-related properties - use `SuspendLayout`. In the process of adding items, use `BeginUpdate`

**Update**

The mechanics a bit different. `BeginUpdate` suppresses paint events during item add/remove. If you ever try to debug a `paint` event, you probably see that it fires a lot.

`SuspendLayout` suppresses layout calculation during move, resizing, etc.

Comment: Yes I understand that much. My question is why should there be a difference between drawing a new control vs updating an existing control's layout.