# .NET - Listview add items - optimize performance

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, listview

Given - 
1> An empty ListView - 'listView1'. 
2> A sorted List of 30,000 strings - 'myList'.

To perform - 
To add several thousand items in the listview1 from myList in an optimized way.

```
// Since default sortOrder is set to Ascending, everytime an element is added in the listview, it will sort the entire listview. If there are several thousand elements in the list, then this could cause serious speed delays.

this.listView1.Sorting = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending;
protected void addbutton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var watchFinal = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var myList = new List<string>();
    var items = new List<ListViewItem>();
    String tempStr;
    int count = 30000;
    ListViewItem lvi = null;

    // Adding items in the List and then sorting it.
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        tempStr = "Nikhil" +  i.ToString();
        myList.Add(tempStr);
    }
    myList.Sort();

    // BeginUpdate and Endupdate will stop the draw untill everything is loaded in added listview.
    listView1.BeginUpdate();
    listView1.Sorting= SortOrder.None;

    foreach (String str in myList)
    {
        lvi = new ListViewItem(str);
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
    listView1.EndUpdate();
    listView1.Sorting= SortOrder.Ascending;
    // Once all elements are added, then they will be sorted in one go. 

    watchFinal.Stop();
    var elapsedMs = watchFinal.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    var elapsedSeconds = elapsedMs / 1000;
    var elapsedMinutes = elapsedSeconds / 60;
    Console.WriteLine("count: " + count + "; Seconds: " + elapsedSeconds + "; milliseconds: " + elapsedMs + "; Minutes: " + elapsedMinutes);
}
```

results - 
count: 30000; Seconds: 2; milliseconds: 2094; Minutes: 0
count: 60000; Seconds: 4; milliseconds: 4540; Minutes: 0
count: 120000; Seconds: 9; milliseconds: 9774; Minutes: 0

I need **optimize this code**, and hence the timings. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Note -

- Since the items in myList are already sorted, when they are added to the listview, they're already sorted. So we don't really need to sort them again.
  However, I need to keep the SortOrder of listview to Ascending by default. But if I mention this - "**listView1.Sorting= SortOrder.Ascending**;", in the add method, it will in the end, always sort it once again. 
  what's the best way to handle this?
- We can use **AddRange** - which states that "If the ListView.Sorting property is set to a value other than SortOrder.None or if the ListViewItemSorter property is set, the list is sorted after the items are added."
  But isn't it doing exactly what I've implemented?
- How to disable automatic sorting in listview? If I want to remove "listView1.Sorting= SortOrder.Ascending;" from the below code, so the method doesn't sort the list again, but I still want to keep the list's default SortOrder to Ascending, so if we do any other operation, the list remains sorted, then what can be done?

Comment: Option A) Use the collection as a datasource to a DGV instead of a LV as it is more well suited to the job Option B) Create a collection of LV items and add them all at once Option C) use SuspendLayout before / ResumeLayout afterwards

Comment: (Option C)
According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619156/difference-between-suspendlayout-and-beginupdate - "SuspendLayout has no effect at all on ListView, ComboBox or ListBox, those controls don't perform layout".  

Whereas

"BeginUpdate stops a control from repainting itself. You do use it on controls like ListView or ListBox when you add items to them in bulk and can't use their Items.AddRange() method - (option B) for some reason."

Comment: @user2769790: The way this is usually optimized is to use paging. The only other improvement to your existing approach would be to create a `ListViewItem[]` and add that with `.AddRange()`.

Comment: Sort them, then add an initial chunk, enough that you've filled the screen. Then start adding batches in intervals triggered by a timer. The goal for this is to keep adding stuff, but let the UI be responsive. You can test it to see how long to wait and how many items to add in a batch to be responsive and make it user friendly.  Ooh, there's a virtual mode in the winforms listview. That may be a better option.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield -  
If in my given code, I add "listView1.Sorting= SortOrder.Ascending;" just before "listView1.EndUpdate();" instead of calling that afterward, would it do the same thing as AddRange(ListViewItem[]) method does? How will .AddRange be of any help in this case?

Comment: @user2769790: Did you try it?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield - AddRange seems to work wonders. 

count: 30000 = Seconds: 0; count: 120000 = Seconds: 1;count: 240000 = Seconds: 2.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield - With AddRange, we don't even have to add beginUpdate and endUpdate before and after calling AddRange method? For sorting, it will pick what is the default sort after adding everything to the list and then sort it just once. Right?

Comment: @user2769790: Right

Comment: The moment the code calls "listView1.Sorting= SortOrder.Ascending;", it sorts the entire list again. If I want to keep the code (that I posted) the way it is and just remove "listView1.Sorting= SortOrder.Ascending;" from the end, so that it doesn't sort it again on the method call. However, I want to keep it defaults Sort property to Ascending so that if I perform some other operation, it should keep the list sorted. Can I do that?

Comment: @user2769790: Comments are not for asking further questions. A posted answer has apparently solved this issue. You can either accept it or not, it's up to you. If you have another question, you should post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [`AddRange(ListViewItem[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c1wawcw(v=vs.110).aspx_) method of `ListView.ListViewItemCollection`.

It would be more efficient to sort your items before calling `EndUpdate()`, and with the `AddRange` method it will automatically sort your items *after* adding them (provided that you set the sorting order beforehand).

If you didn't want to do this then another *small* increase in efficiency would be to do:

```
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(str));
```

rather than:

```
lvi = new ListViewItem(str);
listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Comment: If in my given code, I add "listView1.Sorting= SortOrder.Ascending;" just before "listView1.EndUpdate();" instead of calling that afterward, would it do the same thing as AddRange(ListViewItem[]) method does?

Comment: @user2769790 No, you need to actually call the [`sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.sort(v=vs.110).aspx) method if you aren't setting the `sorting` property before adding the items. `AddRange` is an exception to that rule. (still do it before calling `EndUpdate()` though - otherwise you're drawing a fairly large list view an extra time)

Comment: I noticed that the moment it calls ""listView1.Sorting= SortOrder.Ascending;"", it sorts the entire list again. If I want to keep the code (that I posted) the way it is and just remove "listView1.Sorting= SortOrder.Ascending;" from the end, so that it doesn't sort it again on the method call. However, I want to keep it defaults Sort property to Ascending. How can I do that?

Comment: @user2769790 set the sort order in the spot where you are currently setting it to none (right after you call `BeginUpdate`) or in the initialization of your control, that way you can make this a repeatable function with less redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to add 120000 items to your listview. It is A LOT! In this case I would have used **VirtualMode** option of listview. Here is [example](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2010/06/21/140545.aspx).

In this case other logic probably will have changed:

> We no longer have the Items collection which would throw exceptions when we would try to use it. The SelectedItems collection is also gone. Instead the SelectedIndices is your friend. Well nearly I found that my items were deselected without beeing notified by the ItemSelectionChanged event so I stored the last selected item index by myself when the SelectedIndicies collection was not empty.