# Make a CustomListBox to add BorderColor then can't use ListBox normal properties/methods

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm trying to change the border color of a ListBox.

I made this custom control where i have a function that makes the border by drawing.

After had it working, noticed that can't use ListBox.Items anymore, methods such as .Add() or .Clear().

Code of the Custom ListBox:

```
class CustomListBox : UserControl
    {
        //Fields
        private Color borderColor = Color.MediumSlateBlue;
        private int borderSize = 1;


        //Items
        private ListBox Listb;

        //Properties
        [Category("Custom")]
        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get { return borderColor; }
            set
            {
                borderColor = value;
            }
        }

        [Category("Custom")]
        public int BorderSize
        {
            get { return borderSize; }
            set
            {
                borderSize = value;
                this.Padding = new Padding(borderSize);//Border Size
                AdjustListBoxDimensions();
            }
        }




        public CustomListBox()
        {
            Listb = new ListBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // ListBox
            Listb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            Listb.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            Listb.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(249)))), ((int)(((byte)(249)))), ((int)(((byte)(249)))));
            Listb.FormattingEnabled = true;
            Listb.ItemHeight = 24;
            Listb.Location = new Point(567, 64);
            Listb.Name = "CustomListBox";
            Listb.Size = new Size(235, 936);
            Listb.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(Listb_DrawItem);

            this.MinimumSize = new Size(200, 30);
            this.Size = new Size(200, 30);
            this.Padding = new Padding(borderSize);//Border Size
            this.Font = new Font(this.Font.Name, 12F);
            this.ResumeLayout();
            AdjustListBoxDimensions();

        }

        // Highlight event
        private void Listb_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            Color backgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 50, 50);
            Color horizontalColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100);


            if (e.Index >= 0)
            {
                SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) ? horizontalColor : backgroundColor);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(sb, e.Bounds);
                string text = Listb.Items[e.Index].ToString();
                SolidBrush tb = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, tb, Listb.GetItemRectangle(e.Index).Location);
            }
        }

        //Adjust Dimension (Still in test)
        private void AdjustListBoxDimensions()
        {
            Listb.Location = new Point()
            {
                X = this.Width - this.Padding.Right - Listb.Width,
                Y = Listb.Height
            };
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Graphics graph = e.Graphics;
            //Draw border
            using (Pen penBorder = new Pen(borderColor, borderSize))
            {
                penBorder.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
                graph.DrawRectangle(penBorder, 0, 0, this.Width - 0.5F, this.Height - 0.5F);
            }
        }



    }
```

My problem is that i can't use the ListBox properties/methods, is there a way to inherit them?

Comment: Does your UserControl have the ListBox already in it?  Your posted code does not have `this.Controls.Add(ListB);`  If it does, then you have to get rid of `Listb = new ListBox();`  It's not clear from your posted code how your UserControl with the ListBox is setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've made your own control, you have to make your own properties and methods, calling `Listbox`'s methods and getters/setters

something like this:

```
public void Add(object item)
{
    this.Listb.Items.Add(item);
}

public ObjectCollection ListItems
{
    get
    {
        return this.Listb.Items;
    }
    set
    {
        this.Listb.Items.AddRange(value);
    }
}

//etc...
```

Comment: what does this.Listb.SuspendLayout(); and this.Listb.ResumeLayout(); do?

Comment: `SuspendLayout` pauses form of repainting, resizing and other events with control, and `ResumeLayout` resumes. Imagine case where you're adding 10 items to list: items would appear one by one, control would flicker, scrollbox would be changing with every addition. Beacuse of that, it's advised first to suspend control, do your stuff and then resume layout

Comment: @Filipe You don't need SuspendLayout\ResumeLayout when adding items to a ListBox.

Comment: Did the .add() method as you said but it didn't change the listbox

Comment: @LarsTech you're right. Removed it to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void Add(object item)
    {
        this.Listb.BeginUpdate();
        this.Listb.Items.Add(item);
        this.Listb.EndUpdate();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        this.Listb.BeginUpdate();
        this.Listb.Items.Clear();
        this.Listb.EndUpdate();
    }

    public int SelectedIndex()
    {
        return this.Listb.SelectedIndex;
    }

    public object Item(int index)
    {
        return this.Listb.Items[index];
    }
```

Add to code:
Dock=Fill
This.control.add(listb)

Comment: here the methods

Comment: You don't need SuspendLayout\ResumeLayout when adding items to a ListBox.  See [Difference between SuspendLayout and BeginUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21633852/719186)

Comment: @LarsTech add doesn't seem to work, do you know why?

Comment: Is `Listb` the ListBox that's on the UserControl?  Doesn't sound like it is.  I don't see where you add it to the UserControl control's collection.

Comment: @LarsTech i did NameLB.Add(item); then the list box didnt change.

Comment: No, where is `this.Controls.Add(Listb);`?

Comment: Or if you have the ListBox already on the UserControl, then get rid of this: `Listb = new ListBox();`

Comment: @LarsTech it wasn't and now is extremely bugged, i will post a image

Comment: @LarsTech doesn't work without Listb = new ListBox();